# saving form data in cake1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a strange problem in my app. I have a form with some data to edit, when I am trying to save the data, strange things happens.

If I put `die('test');` at the end of `beforeFilter()`, I see "test" on my screen, but if I put it on the beginning of my action, I am redirected to the login page.

It's happening only if I pass some specyfic data

```
$this->data['Movie']['title'])
```

if I pass something else

```
$this->data['Movie']['genere']
```

everything works fine.

How can I debug it? What is happening between beforFilter and action?

Comment: can you var_dump($this->data) in beforefilter ?

Comment: It might be happening after that - don't forget beforeRender(). Also, check your view isn't pulling in data via requestAction() which might require authentication.

Comment: show complete beforFilter action code...

Comment: array(2) {
  ["Music"]=>
  array(16) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["genere"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
    ...
  }
  ["log"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ds"]=>
    string(7) "default"
    ["sql"]=> ...
  }
}

Comment: should beforeRender() be executed after action?

Answer (score 1):

If you `Auth` component is active then check that in your `beforeFilter()` function that you allowed the action for that user.

For example:

```
function beforeFilter() {
  $this->Auth->allow( array('add', 'edit', ) );  // for example
}
```

Within your `allow()` method include the name of the desired method.

Comment: displaying and saving form is in the same action, displaying is working fine, so it shouldn't be Auth->allow()... besides, i have deny('*');. I'm using Acl and i'm logged in as user with privileges to all in ACO 'contorllers'